# Why are hashCode() and getClass() native methods?

Tags: java, c++, c, methods, hashcode

I checked the source code of `Object` class where I found that method declaration of `getClass()` was

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

And the declaration of `hashCode()` was

```
public native int hashCode();
```

Why are these two methods `native` methods in the class and how can I get the source code of those methods?

Comment: not a duplicate - the OP knows what native is, but wants to know _why_ these two methods specifically are.

Comment: hashCode() is native because the way in which data is stored can differ on unalike operating systems.  I'm not sure why getClass() is though; possibly due to differing implementations of polymorphism.

Comment: @Vulcan getClass() is final so you can't override it and break the type system.

Comment: @EJP I know why it's final, but not why it's native.  As I said in my last comment, my only guess would be due to differing implementations of polymorphism.

Comment: Well, `hashCode` could be implemented with `System.identityHashCode`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can find the complete source code of the native methods [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7)

I hope this will work for you.

These are native methods, because it has to interact with the machine. Here machine dependent code is written in the C language, which is not coming with the source package or in `rt.jar` of the `lib` location of the [Java Runtime Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Execution_environment) (JRE).

One more reason for being native is possibly for the performance reasons. Due to the C level programming performance may be improved, hence they may have written the native code in the C language.

The methods are native because they concern native data. The `hashCode` method returns an integer value dependent on the internal representation of a pointer to an object on the heap.  The `getClass` method must access the internal `vtbl` ([virtual function table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)) that represents the compiled program's class hierarchy. Neither of these is possible with core Java.

Comment: `The hashCode method returns an integer value dependent on the internal representation of a pointer to an object on the heap.` That doesn't seem to be the case from looking at the [source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp#l555).

Answer (score 40):

Source code for Object class can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/native/java/lang/Object.c)

This source contains implementation of getClass() method (See line 58). hashCode is defined as a function pointer JVM_IHashCode (See line 43).

JVM_IHashCode is defined in [jvm.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp). See code starting from line 504. This in turn calls ObjectSynchronizer::FastHashCode which is defined in [synchronizer.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp). See implementation of FastHashCode at line 576 and get_next_hash at line 530.

Probably, the methods are native for performance and due to practical issues w.r.t implementation.

For e.g., From javadocs, hashCode is typically implemented "by converting the internal address of the object into an integer". This internal address is not available via java sdk and will have to be implemented as a native method.

Please read [Is it possible to find the source for a Java native method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032292/is-it-possible-to-find-source-for-java-native-method).  Also read this blog post [Object.hashCode implementation](http://blogs.tedneward.com/CommentView,guid,eca26c5e-307c-4b7c-931b-2eaf5b176e98.aspx). It gives more details. But makes a wrong assertion that hashCode is not generated from object's identity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then how can we say that JVM is platform independent ?

Comment: How would this break platform independence? For any object, hashCode is not required to be same across platforms. For that matter, it wont even be same on the same platform, across different runs. Try public class TestHashCode {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Object o = new Object();
  System.out.println(o.hashCode());
 }
}

Comment: @BhavikAmbani This is terminology nitpicking, but *JVM* is not platform independent, but rather the platform-dependent part, which executes the platform independent Java bytecode on a given platform.

Comment: @hyde Thats what I am saying, refer my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The information for these is in the header (for the class) or elsewhere (for the hashCode) This is not something you can implement in Java.  The source for these methods is in the source for the JVM. e.g. you can download the source for OpenJDK.