# hashCode, notify and wait are implemented using which programming language?

Tags: java, native, wait, hashcode, notify

I was checking Object class in java and found that hashCode, notify, wait and few other methods are native methods.

```
public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;
```

Are these methods not implemented using java language? 
Some other programming language (i guess C) is used to implement these methods?

Kindly help me in getting clear picture here.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900736/what-are-native-methods-in-java-and-where-should-they-be-used  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for

Comment: Hey Alex, I want to know specifically about these methods of Object class. Concept wise I know why native keyword is used in Java.

Comment: This native methods implemented in JVM code via C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are hashCode() and getClass() native methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578764/why-are-hashcode-and-getclass-native-methods)

Comment: Your question is underspecified because each JVM implementation can do it differently. In the case of HotSpot it's C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to use C as the `hashCode()` works on the Objects header.

notify/wait uses system calls which are not available any other way.